# Is there any way to count two times the same date column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),accounting.dates,103) as date_of_acc, numbers,
count(accounting.dates) as total from #a
left join accounting on #a.code = accounting.code
where numbers in (5,74)
group by accounting.dates,numbers
order by date_of_acc,numbers;




 date_of_acc    numbers  total
 01/07/2019        5      43
 01/07/2019        5      53
 01/10/2019        5      72
 01/10/2019        5      40
 01/10/2019        5      44
 01/10/2019        5      71
 01/10/2019        5      76
 01/10/2019        5      77
```

I need to count column "date_of_acc" again because he didn't count me all up in one date in particular,
what i need is this one date  "01/07/2019" to be one value and that total need to be sum in one.
This also applies to other date values.

Comment: MySQL? Really? Does MySQL have a CONVERT(..., 103) function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below - add `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),accounting.dates,103)` in group by

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),accounting.dates,103) as date_of_acc, numbers,
count(accounting.dates) as total from #a
left join accounting on #a.code = accounting.code
where numbers in (5,74)
group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),accounting.dates,103),numbers
order by date_of_acc,numbers
```

Comment: That's what i need, thanks. I forget that i can put the whole CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),accounting.dates,103) in GROUP BY statement.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
group by accounting.dates
```

will produce separate group for same date but different hour, minute, second and millisecond. You need to group by the date part only:

```sql
select convert(varchar(10), cast(accounting.dates as date), 103) as date_of_acc
     , numbers
     , count(accounting.dates) as total
from #a
left join accounting on #a.code = accounting.code
where numbers in (5,74)
group by cast(accounting.dates as date), numbers
order by date_of_acc, numbers;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you change you sql to this you'll see why multiple rows of the same date are appearing:

```
select 
  accounting.dates as date_of_acc,   
  numbers,
  count(accounting.dates) as total 
from #a
left join accounting on #a.code = accounting.code
where numbers in (5,74)
group by accounting.dates,numbers
order by date_of_acc,numbers;
```

accounting.dates will have some variance (like a time perhaps) where multiple dates have same dats but different times. The grouping is done with the time included and then the time is stripped off when the dates are presented leaving you wondering why the same day date shows up multiple times

This is permitted in sql (to group by a value then change the value before it is presented) but not what you want

To fix it, perform the CONVERT in both the select AND ALSO in the GROUP BY. This means it will be the converted dates that are grouped and counted; there's no need to "do it again"- we just need to make sure the data is shaped how we want the first time it is grouped

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you correctly. In the example that you show you'd like to receive:

```
date_of_acc      numbers    total
01/07/2019       10         96
01/10/2019       30         380 (if I calculated correctly)
```

If yes than you should probably change your query to:

```
select
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),accounting.dates,103) as date_of_acc,
    SUM(numbers), -- Here changed
    count(accounting.dates) as total
    from
        #a
        left join accounting
            on #a.code = accounting.code
    where
        numbers in (5,74)
    group by
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),accounting.dates,103) -- Here another change
    order by
        date_of_acc -- and last one
```

If it doesn't do what you want, please, elaborate on your problem.